# k-times differentiable functions on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Is $C^k[0,1]$ (the set of all k-times differentiable function, not necessarily continuously) complete with respect to the norm $\|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty +\cdots+\|f^{(k)}\|_\infty$?

I know the argument that this is true for the space of k-times continuously differentiable functions, but is it true for just $k$-times differentiable functions?

Comment: $C^k$ is the space of $k$-times *continuously* differentiable functions. You may want to edit the question to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Sorry, in the question I'm reading it is denoted differently.

Comment: That is unfortunate. However, the $k$-th derivative of a $k$ times differentiable function can be unbounded, so the norm isn't well-defined.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a typo, because I was thinking the same exact thing.

Comment: @DanielFischer What if we restrict to functions with bounded derivative? Derivatives are Baire 1 functions, and the uniform limit of a (Cauchy) sequence of bounded Baire 1 functions is again a bounded Baire 1 function, so a negative answer cannot proceed on entirely abstract grounds.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo If we require the $k$-th derivative to be bounded, I think it should be complete. But I'm not sure, the criteria for when the integral of a measurable function is everywhere differentiable are delicate, iirc.